# Should be JS functions defined as async after introduction of "Top-level await"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Starting Node.js [14.3.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V14.md#support-for-top-level-await) it's now possible to use the `await` keyword outside of `async` functions, with the `--experimental-top-level-await` flag.

At the same time, the [explanation](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) in V8 blog says:

> *Top-level `await` only works at the top level of modules. There is no support for classic scripts or non-async functions.*

For me it sounds a bit controvering.
On the one hand, *«outside of `async` function»* can be understood as «not only in `async` function, but **elsewhere outside of it** as well», on the other hand, *«only works at the top level of modules and there is no support for non-async functions»*.

As I understand, what's written in Node.js changelog, within the JS modules (ES6 Modules, e.g. *.mjs) there is no need anymore to specify each function, containing `await` as an `async` function.

My questions:

1. Could someone clarify the policy of the usage of `async` after introduction of Top-level await in Node.js 14.3.0?
2. Should I still use `async` as a keyword for function definition in ES6 Modules running on recent Node.js versions?

Comment: `there is no need anymore to specify each function, containing await as an async function` - is that something you read somewhere? because I couldn't find that statement in your link - so, I would say that you still need to tag a function as `async` if you want to use `await` within it - unless you can sow where your statement comes from

Comment: @JaromandaX, _«there is no need anymore to specify each function, containing `await` as an `async` function»_ is my interpretation of _«it's now possible to use the `await` keyword outside of `async` functions»_.

Comment: the bit in yellow? it says `Top-level await only works at the top level of modules` - it doesn't say you don't need to use `async` for functions that use await - please highlight the section where it states *there is no need anymore to specify each function, containing await as an async function* - or copy it verbatim, because that sentence does not exist at that link

Comment: the onlu use of the word `specify` in your new link has nothing to do with async/await ... *specify unit of time passed to fs.utimes* - you made a statement as if it were fact ... are you actually asking a question where you've made that statement?

Comment: *Support for Top-Level Await

It's now possible to use the await keyword outside of async functions* - see, it's still JUST TOP LEVEL AWAIT

Comment: The quoted text even says "There is **no support for** classic scripts or **non-async functions**." Doesn't get much clearer than that.

Comment: Not sure how you're getting from "outside of async functions" to "inside non-async functions", especially given the context of **top-level await**.

Comment: @ChrisG, I've elaborated the question.

Comment: It's perfectly clear. Let me paraphrase: "Up until now, await could only be used inside an async function. Starting now, it can also be used outside an async function." This says *nothing* about whether functions that use await inside need `async` or not in their declaration, so again: I have no idea why you're making this leap.

Comment: «This says _nothing_ about whether functions that use `await` inside need `async` or not in their declaration» — in my opinion, if there is no **explicit** statement, that `await` is mandatory, then it can be omitted. Previously, it used to be clear, `await` can be used only in `async` function. Now, it says _nothing_, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Well, if statement A says nothing about situation B, why would you assume situation B has also changed, and in a very specific way on top...? It just makes no sense at all, sorry. (And again: the text even specifically states that the concept of "using await without async" does not apply to non-async functions.) You have also just introduced a *third* concept: "`await` is mandatory". Again, I have no clue where you're pulling these statements from.

Comment: «`await` is mandatory» — it's a typo error, of course, I mean «`async` is mandatory». Statement A changes behaviour of `await`/`async` on the top level and I wanted to clarify the situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214323/discussion-between-mike-b-and-chris-g).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for top-level `await` has *no bearing at all* on whether you should declare a function as `async` or not.

Declare a function as `async` if you want to use `await` inside it.

Since declaring a function as `async` makes it return a promise, most of the time you will not want to do this.

---

> Top-level await only works at the top level of modules. There is no support for classic scripts or non-async functions.

This just means that the top-level await feature only works:

- At the top-level. It doesn't let you `await` inside a function that isn't `async`. i.e. There is no change to the way `await` works *inside* functions.
- In a module.

Answer (score 1):

For context, it's usually only possible to use the `await` keyword *inside `async` functions.* I.e.:

```
async function foo() {
    await bar();
}
```

This has so far *not* been possible:

```
// top level, no function
await foo();
```

You needed to do one of these two things:

```
(async function () {
    const baz = await foo();
})()

foo().then(baz => ...);
```

With this *top level `await`*, this *is* now possible:

```
// top level, no function
const baz = await foo();
```

That is all. It doesn't change anything else. You still need to make `async` functions `async` and you still need to use `async` functions if you want to use `await` within them. Basically, your top level is now implicitly wrapped in an `async function () { ... }`.